# How to implement custom controllers in Umbraco 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, umbraco

I am having trouble getting my custom controllers to behave properly in an Umbraco MVC site. I can't work out how to pass custom models and use custom ActionResults. When I try to send a form the method is not being called. So a method like this

```
public ActionResult Home(string username, string password)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("form");

    var company = new Company();
    return CurrentTemplate(company);
}
```

that should be called from a form like this but nothing happens.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Home","Login", FormMethod.Post, new {name = "logon"}))
{
    <label>User name </label><input type="text" id="username"/><br/>
    <label>Password </label><input type="password" id="password"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Here"/>
}
```

I know it is possible to override the default controller but is there any point in doing so?

Comment: This seems more as a question on general asp.net mvc practice than umbraco to me. Did you set the ViewModel in your view-file? Ie @model yournamespace.viewmodels.Company
?

Comment: @Eric Herlitz this is umbraco specific. I am forced at the moment, according to the docs, to have one controller per doctype and an actionresult per template. I am finding it confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Umbraco, every request is routed through the `Umbraco.Web.Mvc.RenderMvcController` but you can override this and the [documentation is here](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Mvc/custom-controllers).

However, I would suggest that if you feel you need to do this then you are possibly over-complicating your implementation. You can still use your approach to render ChildActions which can be given a model independent of the Umbraco page model. [See here](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Mvc/child-actions). This is great for things like rendering paged search results, document listings and content you want to be able to control in a controller. I use this approach a lot but always try and pass back a model centered around the `IPublishedContent` interface (e.g. `IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>` for a page listing), that way in the View, you can still have access to the Umbraco content and API from the View instead of having to implement too many of your own properties in a model.

When it comes to posting forms it's a little more tricky because you have two options:

1. As Dan Diplo says, you can use the `Html.BeginUmbracoForm()` approach; or
2. You can post back to a `[HttpPost]` action in the standard MVC way, i.e. `Html.BeginForm()`.

The challenge with (2) is that because all requests are passed through `Umbraco.Web.Mvc.RenderMvcController`, you cannot tell a form which page to post to. You can only post to itself or a non-Umbraco-controlled action. You could for example let the form post back to the same page and have a second ChildAction specifically for the `[HttpPost]`. The issue with this is that it would catch all posts regardless of the form being posted from.

Personally, I use approach (1) in most standard forms where I need to interact with Umbraco directly, e.g. enquiries, uploads etc. and I use approach (2) when I need more control. But this generally needs a lot more thought.

Answer (score 2):

Old post, but I thought I'd add my findings from a current project I'm working in.

For posts, as you're referring to in your form, you'd need a SurfaceController for most instances as @Digbyswift said.

**HOWEVER** - this is where I had the most trouble. I have a form that posts to another page, which displays results, and then displays that data on a view. I wanted to get away from using `query strings` and putting data in `session`, etc, since we're using `MVC`. This also allowed me to return a custom view that also used `CurrentPage`, which you need to have `RenderModel` as the `model`. We're going to need to set up a few things:

1) Create your controller, view, and document type. In this instance, I was dealing w/ "members", so I created a `Member` doc type, `MemberController`, etc.

2) On the view that's posting to the form:

```
        <form method="post" action="member">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" id="query" name="query" class="form-control" placeholder="Member Company or State" />
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Search" class="button button-green" />
        </form>
```

You could also define a custom route in a class that inherits from the `ApplicationEventHandler` class and register the route in the `ApplicationStarted` event, but this way we'll just override the `Index` action.

3) On the controller, `MemberController`

```
public class MemberController : RenderMvcController
{
     [EnsurePublishedContentRequest(2303)]  // 2303 is your node ID
     public ActionResult Index(string query)
     {
         // your code - assign to ViewBag

         return View("~/Views/Member.cshtml", this.CreateRenderModel(Umbraco.TypedContent(2303)));
     }
}

private RenderModel CreateRenderModel(IPublishedContent content)
{
    var model = new RenderModel(content, CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture);

    //add an umbraco data token so the umbraco view engine executes
    RouteData.DataTokens["umbraco-doc-request"] = model;

    return model;
}
```

You *DO NOT* have to do this if you do not have any `macros` that need to rendered. In my case I had this view that inherited a _layout.

[Custom MVC Routes in Umbraco](http://shazwazza.com/post/custom-mvc-routes-within-the-umbraco-pipeline/)

We have to do (2) things here. One is to make sure that we get the `PublishedContentRequest`.

The second part is to get the `RenderModel` object. I read a lot of articles in which your base model should inherit from `RenderModel`, and add in some default Umbraco constructors, but I didn't have very much luck with this.

Hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really mean you want a custom controller, or do you actually just want to create a form  in Umbraco using MVC? If it's the latter then you need to use a [surface controller](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Mvc/surface-controllers) ie. ensure your controller inherits from `Umbraco.Web.Mvc.SurfaceController` and has the suffix 'SurfaceController'.

```
public class MySurfaceController : Umbraco.Web.Mvc.SurfaceController
{
    public ActionResult Index() 
    {
        return Content("hello world");
    }
}
```

You then need to use the custom Umbraco Html helper to create your form tags:

```
@using(Html.BeginUmbracoForm("CreateComment", "BlogPostSurface"))
{
 //
}
```

See http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Mvc/forms

Comment: Thanks Dan, I actually want to be able to control everything. At the moment I need to have 1 controller per doctype and then an actionresult for each template and this is confusing me a bit. Is there a way to use my own controllers and methods to control it all?